# How can I determine if something is a bug or not?

Tags: bug-reporting

What's the the best way of ascertaining if something is a bug in ubuntu, as opposed to a problem I could rectify myself?

Comment: You can visit/seach in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu for reported bug

Answer (score 0):

First, see if the problem has already been reported here on Askubuntu.com. Then, see if the problem is indeed a bug and has been reported at launchpad.net. If you can't find any mention of it, ask a question here.